# According to the Star Fleet manual, specifically, how is the Prime Directive worded?

Tags: star-trek

I've heard about it, but I don't think I've seen it or heard it recited.
According to the Star Fleet manual, specifically, how is the Prime Directive worded?

Comment: “Ape shall not kill ape” - wait, wrong movie.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_Directive

Comment: You think they’d give us nerds such potent nitpicking ammunition as an actual wording for the Prime Directive? You think wrong!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Believe it or not, there has never been an official Starfleet Officer's Manual book published by Paramount. The books that carry the "Official Trek" moniker have always focused primarily on the [ships](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Star_Trek_Star_Fleet_Technical_Manual), [technology](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Star_Trek:_The_Next_Generation_Technical_Manual) and [aliens](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Star_Fleet_Medical_Reference_Manual) rather than the crew who man the ships, work the technology and make <s>sweet love to</s> first contact with the aliens.

---

Probably the closest *semi-canon* manual that references the Prime Directive is the [USS Enterprise Officer's Manual](http://www.cygnus-x1.net/links/lcars/USS-Enterprise-Officers-Manual.php) (written by [Geoffrey Mandel](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Geoffrey_Mandel) (later Production Designer for Voyager and Enterprise) and [Doug Drexler](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Doug_Drexler) (later Production Designer for TNG, Voyager and Enterprise). In it we see almost exactly the same wording offered by Kirk in [TOS: Bread and Circuses](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bread_and_Circuses_(Star_Trek:_The_Original_Series))

> No identification of self or mission. No interference with the social
> development of said planet. No references to space or the fact that
> there are other worlds or civilizations.
>
> <sub><sup>TOS: Bread and Circuses</sup></sub>

vs.

> When contacting a planet making normal progress toward a technological
> civilization, an officer of Starfleet shall make no identification of
> self or mission; no interference with social development of said
> planet; no references to space, to other worlds or more advanced
> civilizations.
>
> <sub><sup>USS Enterprise Officer's Manual</sup></sub>

---

That all being said, in [Voy: Infinite Regress](http://www.chakoteya.net/Voyager/509.htm) we see that this simple three line principle is only the tip of the iceberg when it comes to the Prime Directive;

> **NAOMI:** *That's okay. I'll be pretty busy by then. Want to hear the rules of First Contact?*
>
> **SEVEN:** *No.*
>
> **NAOMI:** *How about **the suborders of the Prime Directive? I know all forty seven of them.***